# Force a method wait for timer to stop in c#

Tags: c#, timer

Ok I have a simulator which consists of some methods and a timer. I am starting the timer here :

```
private void StartSimulation(object sender,EventArgs e)
{ 
    while(execList.Count != 0)
    {
        Assign(MF,Mpre);
        retCT = ChooseTransition(execList);
        ttoexec = retCT[1];
        this.time = retCT[0];                     
        timer.Start();
        // I need to stop execution of this method here untill timer stops ticking
        ExecuteTransition(ttoexec);
        execList.Remove(ttoexec);
    }
}
```

And the timer method is like :

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    --time;
    ++k;
    output.Add("t.u : " + k + "  " + "M = [" + MF.GetRowVal() + "];");
    if (time == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

variable time is of type int and holds the number of seconds time needs to tick(is time * 1000 ms of the interval time of timer). Note that in StartSimulation method I am setting time with a value from an array.

**Update**

I am using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

I want my `StartSimulation()` to stop executing until timer is stopped (until the execution of `timer.Stop()` in `Timer_Tick`).The output is a list of strings , which in the end I will write in a txt file .

The issue now is that the execution of `StartSimulation()` is going in same time as the timer ticks , therefore output list have only 1 element (that one I insert in the beginning of `StartSimulation()` code which I didn't paste it here).

So I open the txt file , write in it, close it and timer is still going. The execution of `StartSimulation` should stop when timer.Start() method is invoked

Comment: omg, use interpolation   `$"t.u : {k}  M = [{MF.GetRowVal()}];"`

Comment: Also your question is not clear, please try to explain what you are trying to do, why its not working, and what you expect the outcome to be

Comment: @TheGeneral Ok but that still does not help me to solve my issue :D

Comment: Also what sort of timer is this? there are several in .net

Comment: @TheGeneral How clear you want ? I want my StartSimulation() to stop executing until timer is stopped( until the execution of timer.Stop() in Timer_Tick). output is a list of strings , which in the end I will write in a txt file . The issue now is that the execution of StartSimulation() is going in same time as the timer  ticks , therefore output list have only 1 element( that one I insert in the beginning of StartSimulation() code which I didn't paste it here). So I open the txt file , write in it, close it and timer is still going. The execution of StartSimulation should stop when timer.Star

Comment: @TheGeneral System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Comment: Great explanation, +1, i have updated your question

Comment: is `StartSimulation` run on the UI thread?

Comment: @TheGeneral yes

Comment: @TheGeneral There is a very simple way using Thread.Sleep() in StartSimulation() and everything would work fine but I am not allowed to use that method. I tried with Monitor.Pulse() and Monitor.Wait (like java has wait and notify) but I couldn't find a good implementation as execution of StartSimulation() was still running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok somehow I managed to get it working , will post the code here in case someone need to implement something similar:

```
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        --time;
        ++k;

        if (time == 0)
        {
            ExecuteTransition(ttoexec);
            output.Add($"t.u : {k} M = [{MF.GetRowVal()}];");
            timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            output.Add($"t.u : {k} M = [{MF.GetRowVal()}];");
        }

    }
    private bool isDone()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!timer.Enabled) return true;
        }
    }
    private Task DoAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => isDone());
    }

  private async void StartSimulation(object sender,EventArgs e)
  {  
    ...
    await DoAsync(); // it won't go further unless method isDone() return anything
    ...
   }
```

Comment: That’s a really bad idea, because now you have a thread with a very tight loop using lots of processor resources doing nothing.

Comment: @ckuri It is meant only for educational purposes and the runtime of the application is not meant to be more then 5 mins

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Enabled property.

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.stop?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Timers_Timer_Stop), Stops raising the `Elapsed` event by setting `Enabled` to `false`.

Comment: This is not really the answer to the question, however it is the answer to the title

Comment: Ok but that still doesn't solve it, if you check the code I pasted above there is a while loop  in where code is executed, so I don't want the below code after timer.Start() not to execute if timer.Enabled is false. I want that part of code execute after timer.Enabled is false (Above start.timer() I have a method which is called and the output of that method is not always the same so re calling that method is not what I want)

Comment: @user3720015 My apologies for missing the point. Your solution is the way I would approach it as well, and it's good that you moved to using async-await. I up-voted your answer and you should accept it as well, for the future reference of people encountering your question..

Comment: @CobusKruger Was my fault , as TheGeneral said you answered to the title question, my post was not clear enough. About accepting the answer I will but only in 2 days( I am not allowed to accept the answer now).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, without refactoring your code too much, and sticking to the original spirit of the question.

As you are on the UI thread, one solution is to use `async` `await` pattern to keep the UI responsive, and `AutoResetEvent`. Unfortunately `AutoResetEvent` is not awaitable, however you can build your own

**Given**

```
public class AsyncAutoResetEvent
{
   private static readonly Task _completed = Task.FromResult(true);
   private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> _waits = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
   private bool _signaled;

   public Task WaitAsync()
   {
      lock (_waits)
      {
         if (_signaled)
         {
            _signaled = false;
            return _completed;
         }

         var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
         _waits.Enqueue(tcs);
         return tcs.Task;
      }
   }

   public void Set()
   {
      TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;

      lock (_waits)
         if (_waits.Count > 0)
            toRelease = _waits.Dequeue();
         else if (!_signaled)
            _signaled = true;

      toRelease?.SetResult(true);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private AsyncAutoResetEvent asyncAutoResetEvent = new AsyncAutoResetEvent();

...

private async Task StartSimulation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   while (execList.Count != 0)
   {
      Assign(MF, Mpre);
      retCT = ChooseTransition(execList);
      ttoexec = retCT[1];
      this.time = retCT[0];
      timer.Start();

      // stop here and leaves the UI responsive
      // until its set again
      await AsyncAutoResetEvent.WaitAsync();

      ExecuteTransition(ttoexec);
      execList.Remove(ttoexec);
   }
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    --time;
    ++k;
    output.Add("t.u : " + k + "  " + "M = [" + MF.GetRowVal() + "];");
    if (time == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        AsyncAutoResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

***Note*** : You will need to propagate the `async` `await` backwards through your code with this solution

***Disclaimer*** : There is really other ways to do what you want to do using tasks and a plethora of different reorganizations of your code, though this should work

Comment: thanks for you time but that didn't helped me, it was like running in a infinite loop but I got it to work somehow.